how to hide a div on my html after clicking on it and display an other one on clickjacking attack
hi i am writing this code to hide a div after the user clicks on it and display on the same time an other div so my click jacking attack becomes more interractive with the user i have looked and tried my best but in the end i could not i hope u could guide me through this
note : i am not attacking any one or causing any harm i am just learning on burpsuite labs
thanks in advance
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>clickjacking attack</title>
</head>
<body>


  <style type="text/css">
    #clickme{
      position: absolute;
      text-align:center;
      padding:9px;
      width:200px;
      background-color:gray;
      border-radius:10px;
      color:white;
      top:200px;
      left:1000px;
      font-size:20px;
      z-index:1;
      }
    #clickme2{display:none;}
  </style>

  <div id="clickme" onclick="funci()">click me1</div>
  <div id="clickme2">click me2</div>
<!-- <iframe src="https://0ae400ef04f88bd9856db34f00730091.web-security-academy.net" style="opacity:0.5;position:relative;width:100%;height:1000px;z-index: 2; sandbox"></iframe>-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function funci(){
    var c = document.getElementById('clickme');
    c.style.display = "none";
    var d = document.getElementById('clickme2');
    d.style.display = "block";
  }


  </script>
</body>
</html>



I would advise not using the attribute onclick but rather using an eventListsener for your click event. Furthermore you can toggle a class that styles your elements using your eventListener with a callBack function in your eventListener.

2 id's never be same, change it to class or change ID of both the div. In js take another variable in which make div display to inline, and already set the display value to none of 2nd div.

i have edited it and it worked just fine with out the iframe , when i trie to use the i fram it stop acting like it suppose to i have upadated the code on my post i hope u read it egain
